# Excel Xlookup with Mode (to return the most frequent result)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to do this?

I'm aware Xlookup will return the first result it finds, but what If i want to return the most frequent result?

If the results are what appears below, how do i return Apple?

```
Apple
Apple
Pear
Banana
Orange
Apple
```

Example of Formula

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,A:A,B:B)
```

But, if i try

```
=MODE(XLOOKUP(A1,A:A,B:B))
```

Result is #N/A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XLOOKUP is probably not the correct formula for this.

Instead use INDEX/MODE(MATCH)

```
=INDEX(A1:A6,MODE(MATCH(A1:A6,A:A,0)))
```

[image]

Proof it does not return the first, but in fact the most frequent:

[image]

With LET(just so the range is not repeated multiple times):

```
=LET(rng,A1:A6,INDEX(rng,MODE(MATCH(rng,rng,0))))
```